# Ошибка в задаче python

Tags: python

Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [-9563; -3102], которые удовлетворяют следующим условиям:

1. кратны 7, но не кратны 11 и 23;
2. последняя цифра отлична от 8.

Найдите количество таких чисел и максимальное из них.

Правильный ответ: 723 -3115

При вводе данного кода выдаётся неправильный ответ, в чём заключается ошибка?

```
c=0 
m=0
for i in range(-9563, -3102 + 1):
    if (i%7==0) and (i%11!=0) and (i%23!=0) and (i%10!=8):
        c += 1
        m = i
print(c, m)
```

Comment: попробуй что выдаст `print(-4%3)`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru "2"

Comment: а лучше, `print(-7%10)`

Comment: @TigerTV.ru а так выдаёт 3

Comment: В этом у вас и ошибка.

Answer (score 3):

Остаток от деления получается не отрицательный, а положительный. Поэтому для вашего случая подойдет следующий `if`;

```py
if (i%7==0) and (i%11!=0) and (i%23!=0) and (i%10!=2):
```

Вывод:

```
723 -3115
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите получить положительный остаток от деления, вы можете использовать функцию abs() для получения абсолютного значения остатка:

```
if (i%7==0) and (i%11!=0) and (i%23!=0) and (abs(i)%10!=8):
```